Spotipy not pushing .env file with Credentials | INVALID_CLIENT? HTTP400?
Currently starting my first python project following this tutorial:
Spotify API Tutorial - Save Song Data
After following along, I run the project on terminal and I'm able to quit and see stored songs in the DB, as the project should. However, whenever I attempt to search an artist or whatever word I put in the query, I get the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 256, in _request_access_token
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1024, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    songs = search_songs(search_query)
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/main.py", line 21, in search_songs
    results = sp.search(search_query, limit=10)
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 602, in search
    return self._get(
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 327, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 251, in _internal_call
    headers = self._auth_headers()
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 242, in _auth_headers
    token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 229, in get_access_token
    token_info = self._request_access_token()
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 260, in _request_access_token
    self._handle_oauth_error(http_error)
  File "/Users/baseplate/Desktop/Apps/spotify_to_yt_to_discord/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 139, in _handle_oauth_error
    raise SpotifyOauthError(
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_client, error_description: Invalid client

Now, after hours of looking over the video for spelling or syntax issues and reading through documentation that I may or may not have understood completely, I tried taking apart the code. I can confirm that the ID and Secret codes are correct as I've hard coded them into the 'client_id' and 'client_secret' variables to see if the project would work and it did. Code below.
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from song_model import Song
from song_dao import dao_get_all_songs, dao_save_songs
from db import create_tables
from typing import List

client_id = '09090909090909090'
client_secret = '09090909090909090'

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    )

sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

def search_songs(query: str) -> List[Song]:
    results = sp.search(search_query, limit=10)

    songs = []
    for track in results["tracks"]["items"]:
        song = Song(
            title=track["name"],
            artist=track["artists"][0]["name"],
            album=track["album"]["name"],
            spotify_id=track["id"]
        )
        songs.append(song)

    return songs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_tables()

    while True:
        selection = input('''
                          Enter:
                          s - to search
                          g - to print all songs in the db
                          q - to quit
                          ''')
        selection = selection.lower()

        if selection == 'q':
            break

        elif selection == 'g':
            print("All songs in the database: ")
            all_songs = dao_get_all_songs()
            for song in all_songs:
                print(f"Title: {song.title} Artist: {song.artist} Album: {song.album}")

        elif selection == 's':
            search_query = input("Enter your search: ")
            songs = search_songs(search_query)

            if len(songs) > 0:
                print(f"Songs returned: len(songs)")
                for i, song in enumerate(songs, start=1):
                    print(f"{i}: Title: {song.title} Artist: {song.artist}")

                save_choice = input("Do you want to save these songs (y/n): ")
                if save_choice.lower() == 'y':
                    dao_save_songs(songs)
                else:
                    print("Songs not saved")        
            else:
                print("No songs were found for your search.")

That led me to the thought that maybe I did something wrong in the .env. However, I ran a test to, at least, print the id and secret and see if it's being read at all. Since the project worked when the codes were pasted directly into the variables, it must not be reading, giving me the INVALID_CLIENT error. But, it worked perfectly.
import os

client_id = os.getenv('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
client_secret = os.getenv('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET')

print('ID:', client_id)
print('Secret:', client_secret)

My .env file is set up as so:
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID='9090909090909090909090909'
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET='090909090909099090009'

I think I'm at the end of how much I can figure out at this point, being new to this. At minimum, it's given me a chance to do some diagnosing practice. Thanks for all the help in advance!
